# Can Bootstrap plugins be used with Angular-UI Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm considering [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for use in a new project.  There are also many standard (non-Angular) Bootstrap plugins that I'd like to consider using.

Will "vanilla" Bootstrap plugins work "out of the box" with Angular-UI Bootstrap?  Or, do Angular and jQuery conflict enough to make this a suboptimal combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, but will be very taskly.. Why not use the Angular Bootstrap UI Directives instead?? You will be facing Async issues dealing with `$scope.$evalAsync`

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ..

And from expierence.. I have faced a lot of issues when jQuery and AngularJS Get combined. I wont reccomend with working on both at the same project.. I would just use the directives..

Comment: I do plan on using Angular UI Bootstrap.  In addition to the directives contained therein, there are quite a few standard Bootstrap plugins (not ported to Angular yet) that I'd like to use.  This question is concerning the use of these other plugins.

Comment: @rinogo ill stick to Angualr UI- Bootstrap directives and try to manupilate it...

Answer (score 1):

They will generally work, but using the angular way to do things that were previously done well in jQuery is the way to go.  You will avoid a lot of issues having angular pick up changes and having to deal with $scope.$apply

Answer (score 0):

There basically have no conflict about jQuery and Angular but it's not a good style to mix with those two